# HamStare: Basic automation for chat

Tags: script, chat

### Get it from [Github](https://github.com/fredley/HamStare)!

HamStare is the last word in disapproving stares. Now, roll your own! Out of the box is how it is configured for me, but if you have a little knowledge of Javascript ([or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)), it should be straightforward to modify it for your own use.

**Protip:** Test your modified script in [The Sandbox](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox) to avoid annoying/upsetting people.