# Porkchat: A Chrome extension with lots of chat tweaks!

Tags: script, chrome-extensions, chat

[image]

### Install

**[Install from the Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/porkchat/genlcflidccakbiodbnmjnflfnbkmeip)**

### About

Porkchat is a Chrome extension that bundles together a lot of scripts I have written for Stack Exchange chat over the years. It is fully configurable - each individual script can be enabled/disabled from the options page.

### Included Scripts

- **Dark Theme** - A comprehensive light-on-dark theme, inspired by solarized.
- **More Stars** - Links to persistently show/hide sidebar panes to allow more room for the star list. Good for small screens.
- **PONIES (image hider)** - Images and YouTube previews are shown with 0.1 opacity unless moused-over.
- **Drag+Drop Upload** - Upload images to chat just by dragging and dropping files onto the chat window at any time. Images are not automatically posted, allowing you to edit the message (e.g. making it a reply) before sending.
- **Room Topic Change Diff** - If the room topic changes the topic change message is edited showing the previous and new topic, so you can see the changes.
- **HamStare (Quick text menu)** - Adds a menu for quick text shortcuts.
- **Friday Link Highlighter** - Avoid Rebecca Black's hit single - links are highlighted, and this script checks redirects so can detect links behind shorteners.
- **Message Burner** - Adds a button to 'burn' away messages you don't like, hiding them with an animation.
- **Mod goodness** - whois autocompletion for TL, edit deleted messages, give users write permissions from within a room.

### Why?

All of these scripts are already available here on stackapps as individual userscripts, so why the extension?

- Fast loading - the loading of all these scripts, if you use more than one or two, is vastly streamlined.
- Updates - get fixes and updates automagically
- Contribute - Porkchat is open source and [hosted on github](https://github.com/fredley/Porkchat).

Comment: Original Stack Apps posts for some of the included scripts (the ones I could find, anyway): [PONIES: Hide unwelcome images in chat](https://stackapps.com/q/4344/80368), [Drag+Drop image uploader for Chat](https://stackapps.com/q/6199/80368), [Room Topic Change Helper](https://stackapps.com/q/6201/80368), [HamStare: Basic automation for chat](https://stackapps.com/q/4525/80368), [Set fire to people in chat](https://stackapps.com/q/4331/80368) (i.e. Arqade Fire/Message Burner)

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The interface doesn't close when pressing on the "give explicit write access", which is inconsistent with the behavior of the other buttons upon being pressed. It is also not clear if this worked or not, as there is no feedback and you need to go into the rooms info to make sure it indeed worked

[image]

Comment: Good spot, I've uploaded an updated build that now hides the popup. No other confirmation is given - unlike room ownership these access changes are not broadcast, but unless the endpoint changes the request is very unlikely to fail.

Comment: @fredley Thanks. When the Chrome extension will be updated? It still doesn't work

Comment: It can take up to an hour to go live on the store according to Google. I don't know how often the browser checks for updates though. I think you can manually refresh from the extentions page though. The updated version is 1.0.8.

Comment: Yes, I've forced an update but it still 1.0.7. But that's fine, I'll wait until Chrome will update it's extensions. Thanks again for the great work.

Comment: I've just checked and [Chrome still has the 1.0.7 version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/porkchat/genlcflidccakbiodbnmjnflfnbkmeip) ....

Comment: [Meanwhile, on the dev console](http://i.imgur.com/OmrRqTS.png). No idea what to do about this, I've tried reuploading, lets see if that kicks the new version out.

Comment: Funny, once you posted this comment- it got updated.

Answer (score 1):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Hope you're still updating this...

I'm on the latest version 1.0.18 and using Chrome 65.0.3325.181 on Win 10. The latest update to Chrome extensions has caused a possible bug in the options page of this extension. See screenshot:

[image]

There are more options below "HamStare", but they are inaccessible. A scroll bar is not there as well.

I suspect this is due to Chrome defaulting to `"chrome_style": "true"` in the `manifest.json`, and I think a simple CSS fix would be to just set the proper width and height properties. A quick test with `width: 1000px;` on `<body>` did the trick.

Most importantly, the "Save" button is hidden, and I was unable to get to it through `overflow: scroll`.